# Setting SCL value on emails in exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010, spam

Emails on my Exchange 2010 server do not have a SCL value or X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: in the email header.

Does anyone know how to enable this so I can filter spam from my users

Thanks

Comment: Do you have anti-spam enabled in your Exchange Organization? As far as I know there is no specific parameter to enable or disable the anti-spam stamps, they are there as soon as you enable antispam content filters

Answer (score 2):

You can set both SCL and headers using **Transport Rules**.

In the Exchange Management Console, there are under **Organization Configuration -> Hub Transport**.

For setting SCL, in the **Actions** step, you should flag *set the spam confidence level to value*. For headers, the flag is *set header with value*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cmdlet in the Exchange Management Shell.

```
Set-ContentFilterConfig -SCLQuarantineEnabled $true -SCLRejectEnabled $true -SCLDeleteEnabled $true -SCLQuarantineThreshold 5 -SCLRejectThreshold 6 -SCLDeleteThreshold 8 -QuarantineMailbox SpamQuarantineMailbox@contoso.com -RejectionResponse "Message rejected due to content restrictions" -BypassedRecipients user1@contoso.com,user2@contoso.com
```